# disable copy and paste in TextBox in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, copy-paste

i am developing a windows phone 8 application using c# and i am trying to disable copy and paste in TextBox.
any one can help .

I have tried:

```
private void digitBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (e.Key == (Key.Ctrl | Key.V) ) 
   { 
       e.Handled = true; 
       digitBox.SelectionLength = 0; 
    } 
}
```

thanx

Comment: Show what have you tried.. Some code examples could be nice.

Comment: private void digitBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == (Key.Ctrl | Key.V) )
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                digitBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }

Comment: Roy, you should update your question with that, (I have done it this time)

Comment: I hope you have a very good reason to remove an expected functionality. For example any application that doesn't let me paste in my password, I'll refuse to use. And if I "have" to, I will go on a quest to hunt down the developer... ^_^;

Comment: sure i have a reason I am developing a app for a Bank and the disabling the paste is one of required security issue in all app :P

Answer (score 3):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
   if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
   {
     e.Handled = true;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
   }
  }
```

Comment: the KeyEventArgs  is enherited from Windows.UI.Core or System.Windows.Input?

Comment: I checked on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key(v=vs.95).aspx and it looks like so.